# module 'clips' has no attribute 'SetExternalTraceback'

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, rule-engine, clips, pyclips

We tried running this code in python 2.7 with clips - v6.3, kivy- v1.11.1. The error we are getting is on line **main(sys.argv)** saying "Module clips has no attribute SetExternalTraceback". And we think that this issue arises because pyclips is not installed in our system. But while installing pyclips we are facing the follow issue.

When we tried to install pyclips-1.0.7.343.tar.gz, downloaded from https://pypi.org/project/pyclips/#files, in order to run this code. But we faced a issue that said download Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 from Microsoft website. We successfully installed that, then also it is giving this error.[image]

Github code reference: https://github.com/kdart/clipsdemo

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
"""
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from __future__ import division

import sys
import os
import time

import kivy
kivy.require("1.8.0")

import clips

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.codeinput import CodeInput
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

from lexer import JessLexer # At least close to clips syntax


def _now():
    return clips.Float(time.time())

class ClipsInput(CodeInput):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ClipsInput, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.lexer = JessLexer()
        self.hint_text = "Enter CLIPS code here."
        self.auto_indent = True
        self.background_color = (0.9, 1.0, 0.9, 1.)

    def _keyboard_on_key_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if keycode[0] == 13 and modifiers == ['ctrl']:
            app = App.get_running_app()
            app.do_command()
            return
        super(ClipsInput, self)._keyboard_on_key_down(keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers)


class LoadDialog(FloatLayout):
    load = ObjectProperty(None)
    cancel = ObjectProperty(None)

class SaveDialog(FloatLayout):
    save = ObjectProperty(None)
    cancel = ObjectProperty(None)
    text_input = ObjectProperty(None)

class ReadDialog(FloatLayout):
    read_input = ObjectProperty(None)


class ClipsDemoApp(App):

    def on_start(self):
        clips.RegisterPythonFunction(self._setstate1, "setstate1")
        clips.RegisterPythonFunction(self._getstate1, "getstate1")
        clips.RegisterPythonFunction(self._resetstate1, "resetstate1")
        clips.RegisterPythonFunction(self._setstate2, "setstate2")
        clips.RegisterPythonFunction(self._getstate2, "getstate2")
        clips.RegisterPythonFunction(self._resetstate2, "resetstate2")
        clips.RegisterPythonFunction(self._setstate3, "setstate3")
        clips.RegisterPythonFunction(self._getstate3, "getstate3")
        clips.RegisterPythonFunction(self._resetstate3, "resetstate3")
        clips.RegisterPythonFunction(self._setstate4, "setstate4")
        clips.RegisterPythonFunction(self._getstate4, "getstate4")
        clips.RegisterPythonFunction(_now, "now")
        #clips.RegisterPythonFunction(self.do_read, "read")

    def _setstate(self, num, args):
        lab = { 1: self.root.ids.state1,
                2: self.root.ids.state2,
                3: self.root.ids.state3,
                4: self.root.ids.state4,
                }[num]
        lab.color = (0.1, 0.9, 0.1, 1.)
        if args:
            lab.text = str(args[0])

    def _resetstate(self, num):
        lab = { 1: self.root.ids.state1,
                2: self.root.ids.state2,
                3: self.root.ids.state3,
                4: self.root.ids.state4,
                }[num]
        lab.color = (1, 1, 1, 1)
        lab.text = str("State{}".format(num))

    def _getstate(self, num):
        lab = { 1: self.root.ids.state1,
                2: self.root.ids.state2,
                3: self.root.ids.state3,
                4: self.root.ids.state4,
                }[num]
        return clips.String(str(lab.text))

    def _getstate1(self, *args):
        return self._getstate(1)

    def _getstate2(self, *args):
        return self._getstate(2)

    def _getstate3(self, *args):
        return self._getstate(3)

    def _getstate4(self, *args):
        return self._getstate(4)

    def _setstate1(self, *args):
        self._setstate(1, args)

    def _resetstate1(self, *args):
        self._resetstate(1)

    def _setstate2(self, *args):
        self._setstate(2, args)

    def _resetstate2(self, *args):
        self._resetstate(2)

    def _setstate3(self, *args):
        self._setstate(3, args)

    def _resetstate3(self, *args):
        self._resetstate(3)

    def _setstate4(self, *args):
        self._setstate(4, args)

    def _resetstate4(self, *args):
        self._resetstate(4)

    def do_command(self):
        self.command(self.root.ids.program.text)

    def do_eval(self):
        self.clipseval(self.root.ids.program.text)

    def do_run(self):
        try:
            clips.Run()
        except clips.ClipsError as err:
            self._update(error="ClipsError: {}".format(err))
            return
        self._update()

    def do_step(self):
        try:
            ran = clips.Run(1)
        except clips.ClipsError as err:
            self._update(error="ClipsError: {}".format(err))
            return
        self._update(trace="Ran {} rules.".format(ran))

    def do_reset(self):
        try:
            clips.Reset()
        except clips.ClipsError as err:
            self._update(error="ClipsError: {}".format(err))
            return
        self._update()
        for i in (1, 2, 3, 4):
            self._resetstate(i)

    def do_clear(self):
        try:
            clips.Clear()
        except clips.ClipsError as err:
            self._update(error="ClipsError: {}".format(err))
            return
        _buildfunctions()
        self._update()

    def command(self, text):
        try:
            clips.SendCommand(text, True)
        except clips.ClipsError as err:
            self._update(error="ClipsError: {}".format(err))
            return
        self._update()
        self.root.ids.program.text = ""

    def clipseval(self, text):
        try:
            rv = clips.Eval(text)
        except clips.ClipsError as err:
            self._update(error="ClipsError: {}".format(err))
            return
        self._update(trace="Eval: {}".format(rv))
        self.root.ids.program.text = ""

    def do_update(self):
        self._update()

    def _update(self, error="", warnings="", trace=""):
        ids = self.root.ids
        ids.stdout.text = _reader(clips.StdoutStream.Read)
        ids.display.text = _reader(clips.DisplayStream.Read)
        ids.trace.text = _reader(clips.TraceStream.Read) + trace
        ids.warnings.text = _reader(clips.WarningStream.Read) + warnings
        ids.errors.text = _reader(clips.ErrorStream.Read) + error

    def dismiss_popup(self):
        self._popup.dismiss()
        self._popup = None

    def do_load(self):
        content = LoadDialog(load=self.load, cancel=self.dismiss_popup)
        self._popup = Popup(title="Load file", content=content, size_hint=(0.9, 0.9))
        self._popup.open()

    def do_save(self):
        content = SaveDialog(save=self.save, cancel=self.dismiss_popup)
        self._popup = Popup(title="Save file", content=content, size_hint=(0.9, 0.9))
        self._popup.open()

    def load(self, path, filename):
        self.dismiss_popup()
        try:
            clips.Load(filename[0])
        except clips.ClipsError as err:
            self._update(error="ClipsError: {}".format(err))
            return
        self._update()

    def save(self, path, filename):
        self.dismiss_popup()
        clips.Save(filename)
        self._update()

    def do_batch(self):
        content = LoadDialog(load=self.batch, cancel=self.dismiss_popup)
        self._popup = Popup(title="Run Batch", content=content, size_hint=(0.9, 0.9))
        self._popup.open()

    def batch(self, path, filenames):
        self.dismiss_popup()
        for fname in filenames:
            try:
                clips.BatchStar(fname)
            except clips.ClipsError as err:
                self._update(error="ClipsError: {}".format(err))
                return
            self._update()

def _reader(readmethod):
    out = readmethod()
    if out is None:
        return ""
    rv = []
    while out is not None:
        rv.append(out)
        out = readmethod()
    return "".join(rv)

def _buildfunctions():
    # simpler clips functions to set output indicators
    clips.BuildFunction("setstate1", "?text", '(python-call setstate1 ?text)')
    clips.BuildFunction("getstate1", None, '(python-call getstate1)')
    clips.BuildFunction("resetstate1", None, '(python-call resetstate1)')
    clips.BuildFunction("setstate2", "?text", '(python-call setstate2 ?text)')
    clips.BuildFunction("getstate2", None, '(python-call getstate2)')
    clips.BuildFunction("resetstate2", None, '(python-call resetstate2)')
    clips.BuildFunction("setstate3", "?text", '(python-call setstate3 ?text)')
    clips.BuildFunction("getstate3", None, '(python-call getstate3)')
    clips.BuildFunction("resetstate3", None, '(python-call resetstate3)')
    clips.BuildFunction("setstate4", "?text", '(python-call setstate4 ?text)')
    clips.BuildFunction("getstate4", None, '(python-call getstate4)')
    clips.BuildFunction("resetstate4", None, '(python-call resetstate4)')
    clips.BuildFunction("now", None, '(python-call now)')
    #clips.BuildFunction("read", None, '(python-call read)')

def main(argv):
    app = ClipsDemoApp()
    clips.SetExternalTraceback(True)
    _buildfunctions()
    if len(argv) > 1:
        try:
            clips.Load(argv[1])
        except clips.ClipsError as err:
            print (str(err))
            clips.Clear()
    clips.Reset()
    app.run()

******************** we are getting error in this part ******************

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    main(sys.argv)

******************** we are getting error in this part ******************
```

Answer (score 0):

The traceback indicates that the module is using python2 print syntax, and therefore is not compatible with python3.

The error in your title doesn't appear in your post, so I don't know what that's about, but it probably isn't related to this core issue.

Comment: I have updated my query, please have a look and help if it is possible. Thank you!

Comment: Post this kind of thing as text, not a screenshot.

Comment: And this is now a different question probably with a different answer. I suggest asking it as such - make sure to clearly explain what you're dong.

Comment: Thank You for your advice . we are new to this , can you please suggest a solution for my issue !